# Is it possible in python to kill process that is listening on specific port, for example 8080?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible in python to kill a process that is listening on a specific port, say for example 8080?

I can do `netstat -ltnp | grep 8080` and `kill -9 <pid>` OR execute a shell command from python but I wonder if there is already some module that contains API to kill process by port or name?

Answer (score 22):

You could use the [psutil python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). Some untested code that should point you in the right direction:

```
from psutil import process_iter
from signal import SIGTERM # or SIGKILL

for proc in process_iter():
    for conns in proc.connections(kind='inet'):
        if conns.laddr.port == 8080:
            proc.send_signal(SIGTERM) # or SIGKILL
```

Comment: I have "access denied" running this code. How to "sudo" `proc.get_connections(kind='inet')` ?

Comment: why don't you run the whole thing with `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: Because when it is run on remote server I do not control it directily. And also because the whole thing is running tests in django which fails when run with sudo

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that that wouldn't be the same as running the script with sudo in the first place. If you can't kill it just like that it probably means that the process (the one you are trying to kill) was run with sudo or from a different user, so it needs to be killed using sudo or from that very same user

Comment: redundant `continue`

Comment: I don't think the access denied error is about killing the process. Also I started the process on the same Jupyter notebook without sudo, so sudo shouldn't be required.
I get Access Denied at this line:
  for conns in proc.connections(kind='inet'):

Comment: Solution: Catch exception for processes for which you don't have permission.
try:
for conns in proc.connections(kind='inet'):
       ...
except (PermissionError, psutil.AccessDenied):
                pass

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731665/python-psutil-windows-permission-error

Comment: no sigkill on windows + you need some small delay before trying to reopen the port

Answer (score 5):

You could this with a subprocess and then kill it.

```
import os
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

port = 1234
process = Popen(["lsof", "-i", ":{0}".format(port)], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
for process in str(stdout.decode("utf-8")).split("\n")[1:]:       
    data = [x for x in process.split(" ") if x != '']
    if (len(data) <= 1):
        continue

    os.kill(int(data[1]), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to kill a process on a port is to use the python library: freeport (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freeport/0.1.9) . Once installed, simply:

```
# install freeport
pip install freeport

# Once freeport is installed, use it as follows
$ freeport 3000
Port 3000 is free. Process 16130 killed successfully
```

The implementation details is available here: https://github.com/yashbathia/freeport/blob/master/scripts/freeport

Comment: @KardiTeknomo Do you have freeport library installed?  I have added command to install freeport

Comment: yes, I installed freeport but it does not work. Killing the process manually using netstat -ano | findstr :8080 and taskkill /PID foundPID /F does much better job

Comment: `freeport` [uses lsof](https://github.com/yashbathia/freeport/blob/ea9bda56f40cde903e21aab23c1c792d28a6f663/freeport/freeport.py#L18) and due to that probably doesn't work on Windows. `psutil` from answer above is a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this method, it works for me..!

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

command = "netstat -ano | findstr 8080"
c = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = c.communicate()
pid = int(stdout.decode().strip().split(' ')[-1])
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: ive linked this answer here: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/155

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [killport](https://github.com/dannysepler/killport) python module. It'd be similar to `freeport`, but it uses `psutil` under the hood so it offers windows support as well

```
pip install killport

$ killport 3000
Killing:
❌ python3.7 (pid 47220) on port 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, processes don't *run on ports* - processes can *bind to* specific ports. A specific port/IP combination can only be bound to by a single process at a given point in time.

As Toote says, `psutil` gives you the `netstat` functionality. You can also use `os.kill` to send the kill signal (or do it Toote's way).

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the above solutions that I used:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

command = 'lsof -t -i:' + str(pid)
c = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = c.communicate()
if stdout == b'':
    return
pid = int(stdout.decode())
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, and if there is only one process using the port (can 2 processes even listen on the same port?)

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def kill_process_using_port(port):
    pid = subprocess.run(
        ['lsof', '-t', f'-i:{port}'], text=True, capture_output=True
    ).stdout.strip()
    if pid:
        if subprocess.run(['kill', '-TERM', pid]).returncode != 0:
            subprocess.run(['kill', '-KILL', pid], check=True)
        sleep(1)  # Give OS time to free up the PORT usage
```